# How much kinetic energy would an asteroid need to impact Earth's surface at a speed above it's terminal velocity

Tags: energy, velocity, drag

Hopefully this is on-topic here (as opposed to Space Exploration).

I have searched for answers and found related ones (include [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47754/239166) question on minimum asteroid size to impact Earth), but none seem to answer this specific question.

Given the height and density gradient of Earth's atmosphere, is there a way to calculate the kinetic energy required for an object to reach Earth's surface (from space) before it reaches it's (sea-level) terminal velocity? The object can be assumed to be spherical and indestructible (other than normal ablative interactions with the atmosphere, which influence drag).

It seems as though a relationship depending only on object radius and kinetic energy could be constructed.

Intuitively, such an object would need to be on the order of a very large meteor (100m+ diameter??) to do this.

Comment: The minimum required kinetic energy depends on the size of the asteroid as air resistance is proportional to its cross-sectional area $F_D \propto A$.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what you mean when you say terminal velocity?  The way I usually hear the term used in connection with thing falling and about to hit the surface is that terminal velocity is the speed at which a falling object experiences enough drag to balance out its weight, and the object no longer accelerates.  At the moment of my writing this, your question is phrased in a way that sounds like you're talking about impact velocity.

Comment: I think you want to consider that you lose mass as the meter or goes through the atmosphere. There is a lot of energy lost as the it ablates mass and radiates heat. The mass helps determine the terminal velocity. If I recall once a meteor is more than about 10 tons it retains some of its cosmic velocity. I don’t have a good source though.

Comment: Found this source, point number 12. https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/faqf/#12

Comment: @the_photon The question is about impact velocity being greater than the object's terminal velocity (at 1 atm of air pressure). Every object has a fixed terminal velocity at a certain altitude correct?

Comment: You might try using an online free fall with air resistance calculator to get a feel for the problem:  https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/free-fall-air-resistance#air-resistance-formula